# FrameLayout, LinearLayout and ScrollView , android Studio

Tags: xml, android-layout, android-studio, android-linearlayout, android-scrollview

The main question is that how to design a layout when including a FrameLayout, scrollView and a linearLayout to not overlap each other ?

I have difficulty to achieve my desired interface with the following xml code! 
What I want is to :

have a FrameLayout as a root to put

```
 a ScrollView containing other linear layout, textviews , ... 
 a LinearLayout which contains 4 Buttons
```

Now the output is like this which prevents to click on the buttons.

[image]

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="polimi.aap.yas.personalhealthrecord.EditPersonal">
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/flContent_ep"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:background="@mipmap/generalbtnimg"
            android:id="@+id/btnClearAll_editP"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Clear All"
            />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:background="@mipmap/generalbtnimg"
            android:id="@+id/btnSubmit_editP"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Submit" />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:background="@mipmap/generalbtnimg"
            android:id="@+id/btnChangePass_editP"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Password" />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:background="@mipmap/generalbtnimg"
            android:id="@+id/btnReviewInfo_editP"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Summary" />
    </LinearLayout>
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:scrollIndicators="right"
    android:layout_above="@id/linearLayout2"
    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout_Sc"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:padding="10dp" >
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/txtFirstName_editP"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:hint="First Name ..."/>

           <LinearLayout
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:inputType="date"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:id="@+id/txtDateOfBirth_editP"
                    android:hint="Birth Date ..."
                    android:layout_below="@+id/txtLastName_editP"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
                <Button
                    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/btnCal_editP"
                    android:background="@mipmap/calendaricon"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/txtLastName_editP"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_gravity="right" />
           </LinearLayout>
            <RadioGroup
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:id="@+id/radioGroupGender_editP"
                android:layout_below="@+id/btnCal_editP"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:onClick="showDatePickerDialog"
                android:clickable="true">
            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Female"
                android:id="@+id/rbtn_female"
                android:checked="false"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                />
            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Male"
                android:id="@+id/rbtn_male"
                android:checked="false"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                />
        </RadioGroup>
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/txtAddress1_editP"
            android:hint="Address Line1..."
            android:layout_below="@+id/radioGroupGender_editP"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
            .
            .
            .

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
    </FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Would you please take a look at the above code and tell me why the result is like this?

Comment: where u have to put your button From Bottom side ?

Comment: @harshadpansuriya I want them to be in a linearLayout at the bottom. like what you see in the screen shot, but it seems it's located behind the scrollView.

Comment: try my Answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the ScrollView to this.

```
 <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/scrollView"
            android:scrollIndicators="right"
            android:paddingBottom="80dp"
            android:layout_above="@id/linearLayout2"
            >
```

Comment: yes, it works! , the problem exactly was due to wrong value for layout_height :)

Answer (score 0):

//You should try this...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="myproject.nectarbits.com.multipleparallelasynctask.MainActivity">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <!--<View.... />-->
                    <!--<View.... />-->
                    <!--<View.... />-->
                    <!--<View.... />-->

                </LinearLayout>

                <ScrollView
                    android:id="@+id/scroll"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout"
                    android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent">


                        <!--<View.... />-->
                        <!--<View.... />-->
                        <!--<View.... />-->
                        <!--<View.... />-->
                        <!--<View.... />-->
                        <!--<View.... />-->


                    </LinearLayout>

                </ScrollView>

            </RelativeLayout>
        </FrameLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can have your layout designed like below (Edit your Image resources accordingly)

and give height to your scroll view  programatically by

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
int width = size.x;
int height = size.y;

ScrollView mylout = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollView);
mylout.getLayoutParams().height = height - ((int)(height*0.3));
// 0.3 is for getting 30% of the screen and subtracting it
//from total screen size
```

and your xml will be like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="polimi.aap.yas.personalhealthrecord.EditPersonal">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/flContent_ep"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scrollView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scrollIndicators="right">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout_Sc"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="10dp">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/txtFirstName_editP"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:hint="First Name ..."
                    android:inputType="textPersonName" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/txtDateOfBirth_editP"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/txtLastName_editP"
                        android:ems="10"
                        android:hint="Birth Date ..."
                        android:inputType="date" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btnCal_editP"
                        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/txtLastName_editP"
                        android:layout_gravity="right"
                        android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <RadioGroup
                    android:id="@+id/radioGroupGender_editP"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/btnCal_editP"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:onClick="showDatePickerDialog"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/rbtn_female"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:checked="false"
                        android:text="Female" />

                    <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/rbtn_male"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:checked="false"
                        android:text="Male" />
                </RadioGroup>

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/tx1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/radioGroupGender_editP"
                    android:hint="Address Line1..." />
                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/txt2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/radioGroupGender_editP"
                    android:hint="Address Line1..." />              <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txt3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/radioGroupGender_editP"
                android:hint="Address Line1..." />              <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txt4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/radioGroupGender_editP"
                android:hint="Address Line1..." />              <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txt5"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/radioGroupGender_editP"
                android:hint="Address Line1..." />              <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txt6"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/radioGroupGender_editP"
                android:hint="Address Line1..." />
                <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txt27"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/radioGroupGender_editP"
                android:hint="Address Line1..." />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/txt72"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/radioGroupGender_editP"
                    android:hint="Address Line1..." />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/txt8"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/radioGroupGender_editP"
                    android:hint="Address Line1..." />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/txt9"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/radioGroupGender_editP"
                    android:hint="Address Line1..." />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/txt10"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/radioGroupGender_editP"
                    android:hint="Address Line1..." />


            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnClearAll_editP"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="70dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                    android:text="Clear All" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnSubmit_editP"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="70dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                    android:text="Submit" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnChangePass_editP"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="70dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                    android:text="Password" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnReviewInfo_editP"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="70dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                    android:text="Summary" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>


    </FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```